# Installing pear path definitions

Tags: php, installation, phpunit, pear

While installing pear by following this [guide](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php), I run into choices of paths which I have no idea what they are:

1. *Public Web Files directory* and
2. *Name of configuration file*

i.e. the #9 and #11 when executing `<php.exe> -c <path-to-your-php.ini-location> <path to>\go-pear.phar`

I found the definition [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-pear/) but that seems to be outdated.

So my question is what are the 1) `Public Web Files directory` and 2) `Name of configuration file`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest [this guide](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Installing-PEAR-and-PHPUnit.aspx)? Helped me a great deal. I accepted all default configurations, and in case you have any problem afterwards, you can (for example) change the location of you public web files with the command

```
pear config-set www_dir /new/myPath
```

The configuration file (you actually specify both path and configuration file name) is the file which will contain all pear settings such as where will PEAR executables reside, if the preferred state is stable or beta, and more.

Again, I would just go with the default configurations, knowing that with the command "config-set" you can change them at any time. [This wiki](http://www.installationwiki.org/PEAR_Installer) is quite good, hope this helps.

You are right though, I searched the Pear documentation from head to toes and couldn't find a specific explanation of what those 2 configuration settings are.

Answer (score 2):

## Public Web Files directory

Directory where files for web applications get installed to. You seldom come across packages that use them.

When you use such a package/application, you need to point your web server's document root directory to it.

## Configuration file name

You need to create a custom configuration file for your shared host setup.

How to do it is shown on the top of the page:

```
$ pear config-create /home/user/pear .pearrc
```

Use the full path to this file as config file name.

Comment: I don't get what you mean for `Configuration file anme`

Comment: If you would make it clear on `configuration` I'll pick yours as accepted